# Using SQl Server CE; Possible to Insert Only If Not Exists?

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-ce

I'm trying to verify a simple 1 field table to determine if a record exists before inserting a duplicate.

```
if not exists (select * from url where url = ...)
insert into url...
```

Can someone Help?

Answer (score 4):

Your code example will run in the full version of SQL, or you could rearrange to the following:

```
insert into url
select 'myvalue'
where not exists (select * from url where url = 'myvalue')
```

Answer (score 1):

Just reverse it and add the condition as a where clause predicate

```
 Insert Into Table .... 
  Where Not Exists 
 (Select * From table where ...)
```

... But your basic problem sounds like it might be better solved by putting a alternate key (unique) constraint on the insert table, referencing the url column (I assume Sql CE does Referential Integrity (RI) constraints?)

Answer (score 1):

You might want to read this thread. [performing-insert-or-update-upsert-on-sql-server-compact-edition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728373/performing-insert-or-update-upsert-on-sql-server-compact-edition/1062302#1062302)

In a nutshell a sqlce specific solution (using SqlCeResultSet) will provide the maximum performance.

Answer (score 0):

Use an Outer Join

Insert into X(...)
select blah, blah, blah
from 
    table t left outer join 
    X on t.id=x.id
where
    x.id is null

Answer (score 0):

Granted, this is way past the posting date, but since I've not seen this answered elsewhere in my quick Google search, I thought I'd share how I solved this with SQL CE so others searching might find an answer.

> -- Update existing record's value
> UPDATE myTable 
> SET myValue = 'Hello World' 
> WHERE keyField = 'MyKey';
>
> -- Insert new record if existing record doesn't exist`
>
> INSERT INTO myTable (keyField, myValue)
> SELECT I.keyField, I.myValue
> FROM (
> SELECT 'Hello World' AS myValue, 'MyKey' AS keyField
> ) I
> LEFT JOIN myTable T ON I.keyField = T.keyField
> WHERE T.keyField IS NULL;

Answer (score -2):

You are on the right path with IF NOT EXISTS.  It is better to use IF NOT EXISTS() or IF EXISTS() than a Sub Query because SQL Server will stop scanning rows in the table when it finds the first instance that matches the EXISTS() condition your looking for.  With a Sub Query written in the examples above it will scan the whole table.

A Classic example is the Insert or Update aka the SAVE.

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Table_A WHERE Column_1 = @Parameter)
BEGIN
    --Update Statement here.
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    --Insert Statement here.
END
```

Answer (score -2):

What about something like this:

```
UPDATE Table1 SET (...) WHERE Column1='SomeValue'
IF @@ROWCOUNT=0
    INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES (...)
```

[Source](http://blogs.msdn.com/miah/archive/2008/02/17/sql-if-exists-update-else-insert.aspx)