# Import/update existing rows in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I am working on a hobby app which will contain a large slew of basically-hardcoded data, as well as dynamic user data once I deploy it. I want the ability to update the hardcoded data locally (more `UPDATE`s than `INSERT`s), and then export these data to the server. In other words, I need to dump data to a file, and import it in such a way that new rows (which will be relatively few) are `INSERT`ed, and existing rows (as identified by the PK) are `UPDATE`d. Clearly, new rows can't be `INSERT`ed on the server (or the PKs would potentially clash and issue erroneous `UPDATE`s); this is an acceptable limitation. However, I cannot `DELETE` the rows to be `UPDATE`d, let alone drop the synchronised tables, because the user-accessible tables will have FK constraints on the "static" tables.

Unfortunately, this seems to be very difficult to do. Google and Postgres mailing lists inform me that the "MySQL-like" feature `on_duplicate_key_update` "will be in a new version" (stale information; is it there?), along with a suggestion that "`pg_loader can do it`", with no indication of *how*.

In a worst-case scenario, I suppose I can come up with a home-brewn solution (dump a data file, write a custom import script that checks for PK conflicts and issues `INSERT` or `UPDATE` statements appropriately), but that seems an awfully clumsy solution for a problem that others have surely encountered before me.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Just for my own curiosity - why can't you just do the updates/inserts on the server? Seems like it'd solve all your issues.

Comment: I could; the chief reasons are security (with my home-brewn system I'd rather not expose the core data to attackers...) and the fact that I often work without a net connection.

Comment: There must be something I'm not understanding. How is the data any more vulnerable based on where you do the editing?

Comment: If I do all the editing locally, I can disable all editing (pages, permissions, user accounts...) on the server.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, temp table + some combination on insert/update is the way to go (you dont need to do it in a function, but you can).

For the record, the feature your looking for is the Merge command. Someone wrote a patch for it, but it was never finished. AFAIK no one is working on it now; it certainly isn't in the soon to be released Postgres 8.4.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered running postgresql locally?

1. Dump server data
2. Import locally
3. Turn on query logging
4. Make updates
5. Take query log and run on server
6. Clear query log

Or am I misunderstanding what you're trying to do?

Comment: No misunderstanding: That is definitely a workable solution—I am already running a local postgres server (two, in fact, on laptop and desktop, respectively). It sounds like a solution that requires a little more baby-sitting than ideal (what with having to manage and reset the logs on every server update, and sync that between my two local machines), but it will definitely *work*.

Answer (score 0):

```
create temporary table newdata as select * from table1 where false;
```

Fill newdata with new data, then:

```
start transaction;
create function fill_table1() returns void as
$$
declare
    data record;
begin
    for data in select * from newdata
    loop
        update table1 set
            column1 = data.column1,
            column2 = data.column2
        where id = data.id
        if not found then
            insert into table1 values data.*;
        end if;
    end loop;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;
select fill_table();
drop function fill_table();
commit;
```

This is not tested so it will probably need some tweaking to work. It requires that table will not change while it is running.

Answer (score 0):

This question seems similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728373/performing-insert-or-update-upsert-on-sql-server-compact-edition/731847):

Maybe you could check the solution I provided there.