# SQL Command "An unhandled exception of type SQL CE"

Tags: c#, database, sql-server-ce

I am to trying to execute a nonquery command in c# but it just won't work can someone tell me where I am doing the mistake. For those who try to help me I am trying to get File modification time creation time and last accessed time and put them in a database. Allfiles is a string array where I saved the paths and with a for loop I intend to put them in the database

```
    cmd = new SqlCeCommand(" IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM FileInfo WHERE fpath='" + Allfiles[i] + "') " +
                           " UPDATE FileInfo SET fpath='" + Allfiles[i] + 
                           "',laccesst='" + File.GetLastAccessTime(Allfiles[i]) + 
                           "',lmodt='" + File.GetLastWriteTime(Allfiles[i]) + 
                           "',ctime='" + File.GetCreationTime(Allfiles[i]) + 
                           "' WHERE fpath='"+ Allfiles[i] + "'" +
                           " ELSE " +
                           " INSERT INTO FileInfo (fpath, laccesst, lmodt, ctime) VALUES ('" + Allfiles[i] + "','
    " + File.GetLastAccessTime(Allfiles[i]) + "','" + File.GetLastWriteTime(Allfiles[i]) + "','" + File.GetCreationTime(Allfiles[i]) + "')", cn);
```

The exception is:

```
System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException was unhandled
  HResult=-2147467259
  Message=There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 1,Token line offset = 2,Token in error = IF ]
  Source=SQL Server Compact ADO.NET Data Provider
  ErrorCode=-2147467259
  NativeError=25501
  StackTrace:
       at System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeCommand.ProcessResults(Int32 hr)
       at System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeCommand.CompileQueryPlan()
       at System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeCommand.ExecuteCommand(CommandBehavior behavior, String method, ResultSetOptions options)
       at System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
       at directoryDatabase.Program.Main(String[] args) in c:\Users\Alban\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\directoryDatabase\directoryDatabase\Program.cs:line 36
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:
```

Comment: What is the exception message completely? Share your stack trace as well. You should always use parameterized queries by the way. This kind of string concatenations are open for SQL Injection attacks. http://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: Please post the full exception (including stack trace)

Comment: I guess it must be something related to ```Allfiles``` variable. Can you put your query into string variable, and post the result query here. There must be an error on the query, some typo, etc.

Comment: Sql Server Compact doesn't support IF EXISTS

Comment: Perhaps you could find [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/728373/) helpful for your case

Answer (score 0):

I think you forget to put `Begin..End` on the `IF..ELSE` part.

```
cmd = new SqlCeCommand(" IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM FileInfo WHERE fpath='" + Allfiles[i] + "') " +
                       " BEGIN " + 
                       "UPDATE FileInfo SET fpath='" + Allfiles[i] + 
                       "',laccesst='" + File.GetLastAccessTime(Allfiles[i]) + 
                       "',lmodt='" + File.GetLastWriteTime(Allfiles[i]) + 
                       "',ctime='" + File.GetCreationTime(Allfiles[i]) + 
                       "' WHERE fpath='"+ Allfiles[i] + "'" +
                       " END "
                       " ELSE " +
                       " BEGIN " +
                       " INSERT INTO FileInfo (fpath, laccesst, lmodt, ctime) VALUES ('" + Allfiles[i] + "','
    " + File.GetLastAccessTime(Allfiles[i]) + "','" + File.GetLastWriteTime(Allfiles[i]) + "','" + File.GetCreationTime(Allfiles[i]) + "')" +
                       " END", cn);
```

Comment: SQL Server Compact doesn't support IF EXISTS

Comment: Ah there you go, my mistakes. There is another similar article too that stated SQL CE do not support ```IF```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4652867/if-not-exists-fails-on-sql-ce

Comment: Thanks Martin now I know so I'll just use SQLITE OR SQL