# equivalent to "if not exists" in SQL CE

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-ce

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using SQl Server CE; Possible to Insert Only If Not Exists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/726448/using-sql-server-ce-possible-to-insert-only-if-not-exists)
>   [“If not exists” fails on SQL CE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4652867/if-not-exists-fails-on-sql-ce)

What's equivalent to:

```
if not exists(select Link from Topics where Link = @link) 
  insert into Topics(Link, Title) values(@link, @title);
```

how to I write the equivalent to in SQL Ce? it's possible do this in a query single?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: looks like [Using SQl Server CE; Possible to Insert Only If Not Exists?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/726448/using-sql-server-ce-possible-to-insert-only-if-not-exists)

Comment: @ p.campbell: It's not. I want no use MySql.

Comment: I say about your topic appointed as duplicate of.

Answer (score 2):

SQL CE does not support any procedural extensions, but you can do:

```
Insert Into Table ...
    Where Not Exists
```

Comment: This seems ridiculous to ask. But why not works? `insert into topics(link, title) values('..', '...')
where not exists(select link from topics where link = '..')`